# form attribute in hyperlink beome null

Tags: html, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am passing form attributes in a th:href but  all attribute are null.I am using thymleaf at front-end side.

```
 <div>
   <input type="text" class="ip_text"  placeholder="Name" th:field="${user.Name}"/>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div>
  <input type="email" class="ip_text"  placeholder="Email ID" required="true" th:field="${user.email}"/>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="phone_nm">
  <span class="p_code">+91</span>
  <input type="text" class="ip_text" pattern="^([0-9]{10})?$"
  required="true" th:field="${user.phoneNumber}"/>
  </div>
  </div>


  remove lots of thing to make it simple
  Href:: 

  <a th:href="@{'https://www.instamojo.com/stayuncle/payments-for-stayuncle/?data_amount='+${ hotel.totalPrice + hotel.serviceTaxTotal + hotel.vatTotal }+'&amp;'+'data_name='+${user.Name}+'&amp;'+'data_email='+${user.email}+'&amp;'+'data_phone='+${user.phoneNumber}}" rel="im-checkout" data-behavior="remote"  data-token="059542XXXXXXXXXXX3165a40a" class="button pay_now">pay now</a>
```

in browser URL comes like this ::

https://www.instamojo.com/stayuncle/payments-for-stayuncle/?data_amount=2574.00&data_name=null&data_email=null&data_phone=null

data_email, data_name & data_phone all are null. form has already filled.Some please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Where is the `<form>`  ?

Comment: @Hearner  I have removed to make it  simple.

Comment: Please include all the related information, in template and controller, because it could help here. Also, try to use pipes to build the th:href in a simple way: <a th:href="@{|https://www.instamojo.com/stayuncle/payments-for-stayuncle/?data_amount=${ hotel.totalPrice + hotel.serviceTaxTotal + hotel.vatTotal }&data_name=${user.Name}&data_email=${user.email}&data_phone=${user.phoneNumber}|}" rel="im-checkout" data-behavior="remote"  data-token="059542XXXXXXXXXXX3165a40a" class="button pay_now">pay now</a>

Comment: @PatrickLC, I couldn't paste full code because of character limitation so mailed you over linkedIn.

Comment: @Nand please try to built an example of your issue (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or at least explain the flow in detail.